# Печать Word документа

Tags: c#

Изучаю документацию по работе с Word документами.

Пытаюсь распечатать:

```
app.Documents.Open(namefile);
// Обрабатываю файл
app.ActiveDocument.Save();
app.Dialogs[Word.WdWordDialog.wdDialogFilePrint].Show();
app.ActiveDocument.Close();
```

Документ распечатывается, всё нормально, но помимо этого открывается пустой Word  и не закрывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за чего это может быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Недавно взялся за нормальное решение этой проблемы, ибо грохать процесс было не совсем верным решением. В общем решение проблемы оказалось простым.

После отправление документа на печать я закрыл документ таким образом:

```
Word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close();
```

Но таким образом я закрыл документ, но не саму программу.

Если следовать документации, то должно было помочь это `Word.Application.Application.Quit();`, но не помогло.

А действующим решением оказалось это:

`Word.Application.Documents.Close();` и после этого вызвать  `Word.Application.Application.Quit();`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй скрыть оболочку установив соответствующее свойство

`app.Visible = false;`

Однако, правильнее еще и всю работу с Word в `try - catch` конструкцию запихнуть с вот таким дополнением

```
finally
{
    app.Quit();
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
}
```

Comment: app.Visible = false, не работает, всё равно появляется. Про конструкцию я знаю, я с начало пишу черной вариант, а потом правильно, мне так удобней.

Comment: а пробовал вот это `app.Quit();`? не помогло? Тебе нужно оболочку закрыть послу завершения работы

Comment: Да, всё равно не закрывается. Причём пока вручную не закроешь, следующий файл не даст распечатать.

Comment: Я собственно о чем - вот те 2 стоки в `finally` закрывают все экземпляры указанного приложения. Я когда столкнулся с Офисом, была проблема при отладке, что остаются процессы не закрытыми, и вот этот `finally` мне с этим помог. Что у тебя не так я не понимаю - попробуй через среду (Environment class) закрывать, хотя то не правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756098/print-word-document-from-asp-net-c-sharp-without-ms-office-installed) рекомендуют стороннюю [библиотеку](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FreeSpire.Doc/)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Spire.Doc;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Printing;


namespace Doc_Print
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Document doc = new Document(); 
            doc.LoadFromFile("sample.doc");
            PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
            dialog.AllowPrintToFile = true; 
            dialog.AllowCurrentPage = true;
            dialog.AllowSomePages = true;
            dialog.UseEXDialog = true; 
            doc.PrintDialog = dialog;               
            PrintDocument printDoc = doc.PrintDocument; 
            printDoc.Print();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {               
                printDoc.Print();
            }            

        }
    }
}
```

Это освободит от использования interop.

Comment: пробовал, но отладчик ругается на эту строку doc.PrintDialog = dialog, решения проблемы в интернете не нашёл.

Comment: То есть пример не работает, говорит что Document не содержит определения для PrintDialog.